# How to create an array with leading zeros in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

Not very difficult:

```
#!/bin/bash

hr=(00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23)

for i in ${hr[@]}; do
echo ${hr[i]}
done
```

But:

```
user@userver:$ ./stat.sh
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
./stat.sh: string 7: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

Bash thinks that leading zero means octal number system. What to do?

Comment: `08` is considered octal

Comment: For your convenience, [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically says "i is an array value, not a key. Use directly or loop over keys instead.", "This loops over values. To loop over keys, use `"${!array[@]}"` [(more)](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2302)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brace expansion (ranges, repetition).

To create an array:

```
hours=({00..23})
```

Loop through it:

```
for i in "${hours[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Or loop through a brace expansion:

```
for i in {00..23}; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Regarding your error, it's because in bash arithmetic, all numbers with leading zeroes are treated as octals, and 08 and 09 are invalid octal numbers. All indexed array subscripts are evaluated as arithmetic expressions. You can fix the problem by using the notation `base#number` to specify a number system. So for base 10: `10#09`, or for `i=09`, `10#$i`. The variable must be prefixed with `$`, `10#i` does not work.

You should be printing your array like this anyway:

Loop through elements:

```
for i in "${hr[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Loop through indexes:

```
for i in "${!hr[@]}"; do
    echo "index is $i"
    echo "element is ${hr[i]}"
done
```

If you need to do arithmetic on the hours, or any zero padded number, you will lose the zero padding. You can print it again with printf: `printf %.2d "$num"`, where `2` is the minimum width.

Comment: looks like i do not need array for this at all!

Comment: Probably not. It depends what you're trying to do. There's also: `printf '%s\n' {00..23}` to just to print the hours as a list.

Answer (score 2):

I think your fundamental problem is that you're using each element of the array to index the array itself.

If you want to just print out the array elements, you should be outputting `${i}` rather than `${hr[i]}`. The latter is useless in your current code since element zero is `00`, element one is `01`, and so on.

On the chance that this is a simplified example and you *do* want to reference a different array based on the content of this one, you have a couple of options:

- Realise that the *value* of an integer and the *presentation* of it are two distinct things. In other words, use `0, 1, 2, ...` but something like `printf "%02d" $i` if you need to output it (noting this is only ouputting the value in the *first* array, not the one you're looking up things in).
- Exclusively use strings and a string-based associative array rather than an integer-based one, see `typeset -A` for detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify it's 10-based :

```
echo ${hr[10#$i]}
```

Comment: very nice! # let b=10#0000000000009  , # echo "$b"

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate with:

```sh
for i in ${hr[@]}; do
```

It is iterating the values of the array witch are:
`00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23`

But when within the loop it has:

```hs
echo ${hr[i]}
```

it is using `i` as the index of the `hr` array.

In Bash, an index within the brackets of an array like `[i]` is an arithmetic context. It means while the value of `i=08` the leading `0` within the arithmetic context causes the number to be treated as an octal number, and `8` is an invalid octal number.

If you wanted to iterate your array indexes to process its values by index, then you'd start the loop as:

```sh
for i in "${!hr[@]}"; do
```

This one will perfectly work as it iterates the index into the variable `i` :

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a hr=(00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23)

for i in "${!hr[@]}"; do
printf '%s\n' "${hr[i]}"
done
```

Now if all you want is iterate the values of the `hr` array, just do this way:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a hr=(00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23)

for e in "${hr[@]}"; do
printf '%s\n' "$e"
done
```

No need to index the array within the loop, since the elements are already expanded into `e`.